# slideToggle multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

//After it toggle the content with this button
$('.content_toggle').hide();

$(".link-toggle").click(function () {
$(this).nextAll(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});


   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-toggle">Read more</div>
<div class="content_toggle">
  Hello world
 </div>

<div class="link-toggle">Read more again ?</div>
<div class="content_toggle">
  Another Hello world
 </div>
```

I want to toggle these content one by one,
Like when I click on the first div, its following content toggle.
Then If if click on the second div, its following content toggle.

Not the two at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Change your nextAll to a next to only target the immediately following class not every class below it

`$(this).next(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");`

Answer (score 1):

give them id and use their ids to toggle

```
jQuery(function ($) {

//After it toggle the content with this button, and use next instead of nextAll
$('.content_toggle').hide();

    $("#myfirstDiv").click(function () {
           $(this).next(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#mysecondDiv").click(function () {
           $(this).next(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
    });



});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap

```
<div>
    <div class="link-toggle">Read more</div>
    <div class="content_toggle">
      Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

in a `<div>`.

Then use the `siblings` method:

```
$(".link-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `nextAll`, just use `next`.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

//After it toggle the content with this button
$('.content_toggle').hide();

$(".link-toggle").click(function () {
$(this).next(".content_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
});


   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link-toggle">Read more</div>
<div class="content_toggle">
  Hello world
 </div>

<div class="link-toggle">Read more again ?</div>
<div class="content_toggle">
  Another Hello world
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is doing exactly what you said it should do. This "nextAll" is going to perform the action in all subsequent siblings. See doc: https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Don't use nextAll, but simply next to obtain the desired effect.